# QTreeView color of painted row

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I extented a `QStyledItemDelegate` to draw some pixmaps on the right side of a QTreeView. This works well, however, I realized that the pixmaps can be in front of the text if it gets too long.
[image]

So I tried to draw a rectangle of the same color as the background before drawing my pixmap.

```
void MyItemDelegate::paint(
    QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    ...
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
    ...
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);
    ...
    painter->fillRect(rect, opt.backgroundBrush);
    painter->drawPixmap(topLeft, pixmap);
}
```

I know that all variables are correct except `opt.backgroundBrush`. It's always invisible black, with or without the `initStyleOption` call.

Then I started to check the value of `opt.state` and `opt.features` to pick the color myself. I had some success with the alternating color (`QStyleOptionViewItem::Alternate`) but it's starting to get long and tedious because there are other states (hover and selected) and other OS that may have other states. There must be a simpler way.

So, my question is: How can I get the actual color that will be used to paint the row when I'm in the `paint` method? Or, do you have any other clean way to avoid this situation?

Comment: Do you really need to use `QStyledItemDelegate`?  In the past I've found plain old [`QItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html) to be far more *accommodating* when it comes to subclassing -- it provides the `drawBackground`, `drawCheck`, `drawDecoration`, `drawDisplay` and `drawFocus` protected members that do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.  Just a thought.

Comment: I started with `QStyledItemDelegate` so I wanted to keep it, but you're right, I could do that. I read `QItemDelegate`'s code yesterday and it was understandable; it wasn't simply calling `style->drawPrimitive`. I'll wait for more answer here, then try what you suggest. Thank you for the thought.

Comment: @G.M.I finally did what you suggested 1.5 years ago and it does work. I added "my" solution below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @G.M. I used the `QItemDelegate` class instead of `QStyledItemDelegate` and I do have more control on the drawing process. Notably because of the added [protected functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#protected-functions) like `drawDisplay`. Overriding this method, I can adjust the "display rectangle" to a smaller size than what was calculated by Qt.

```
void ActionsItemDelegate::drawDisplay(
    QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QRect &rect,
    const QString &text) const
{
    const int minX = ...; // x position of the left-most icon
    const int iconsWidth = rect.width() - (minX - rect.x());
    QItemDelegate::drawDisplay(painter, option, rect.adjusted(0, 0, -iconsWidth, 0), text);
}
```

The drawback is that the UI [changes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#qstyleditemdelegate-vs-qitemdelegate) when using `QStyledItemDelegate`. I don't know how to get the benefits of both: normal style and more controls.

Answer (score -1):

I may process differently. I won't start by calling:

```
QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
```

in the first place.

Then, the important part: if you know how much icons there are on your items, you could calculate the bounding rectangle.

How do you know how many icons you have ? Maybe by calling something like:

```
bool hasIcon = index->data(YourAPP::HasIcons).toBool();
```

You could have something like this in your delegate:

```
void MyItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
...
QStyleOptionViewItem o = option;
initStyleOption(&o, index);
bool hasIcon = index->data(YourModel::HasIcons).toBool();
// or
bool hasCustomRole1 = index->data(YourModel::Role1).toBool();
bool hasCustomRole2 = index->data(YourModel::Role2).toBool();

if (hasIcon) {
    // width of your icons, can be like o.rect.height() * numbers of icons
    int width = 0;

    // shrink your first rectangle
    o.rect.adjust(0, 0, -width, 0);

    // create a second rectangle
    QStyleOptionViewItem o2 = option;
    initStyleOption(&o2, index);
    o2.rect.adjust(width, 0, 0, 0);

    // paint your icons
    ...
    painter->drawPixmap(o2, pixmap);
} else {
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I must call `QStyledItemDelegate::paint` because I want the text, checkbox, color, etc. to be painted, then I want to add my icons. [...] Excuse me if this is rude but your code doesn't make much sense. You do nothing with `o`, you don't explain what those rectangle are supposed to do, you call `initStyleOption` twice with the same index, you call `drawPixmap` with a bad argument, etc. I know how to draw the icons, I just want to know the color of the row.

Comment: You didn't the point, unfortunately. Of course the code isn't working as-is. The idea is to split the original drawing area into 2 independant parts : one for the text, the other one for icon(s).